# trigger to auto-populate the email field based on the contact (lookup Field)

Tags: apex, trigger

I have been trying to develop a trigger which isnt working, The requirement is that I have an email field that should auto-populate once contact has been assigned to the case "Seconday_Contact__c" is the contact name and "Secondary_Contact_Email__c" is the email field.

the trigger is

---

```
    trigger populateContactemail on Case (before insert , before update){
Set<ID> setConIds = new Set<ID>();
for(Case  obj : trigger.new){
    if(obj.Secondary_Contact__c != null)
        setConIds.add(obj.Secondary_Contact__c);
}
MAP<ID , Case> mapCon = new MAP<ID , Case>([Select Secondary_Contact_Email__c from Case where id in: setConIds]);
for(Case obj : trigger.new)
{
    if(obj.Secondary_Contact__c != null)
    {
        Case  c = mapCon.get(obj.Secondary_Contact__c);
        obj.eSecondary_Contact_Email__c = c.email;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Why not use a formula field?

Comment: Is `Secondary_Contact__c` a lookup to Case? Looks like it should be a lookup to `Contact`. If that's the case, you're querying the wrong object.

Comment: Secondary_Contact__c is lookup field to contact!.

Comment: Your queries are wrong, then. Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Secondary_Contact__c` is a lookup to `Contact`, you're then querying the wrong object.

This is how I'd do it.

```
trigger populateContactEmail on Case (before insert , before update){
    Set<Id> setConIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Case  obj : trigger.new) {
        if (obj.Secondary_Contact__c != null) {
            setConIds.add(obj.Secondary_Contact__c);
        }
    }

    Map<Id, Contact> mapCon = new Map<Id, Contact>([Select Id, Email from Contact where id in: setConIds]);

    for (Case obj : trigger.new) {
        if (obj.Secondary_Contact__c != null) {
            //Protecting against bad Ids
            if (mapCon.containsKey(obj.Secondary_Contact__c) {
                Contact c = mapCon.get(obj.Secondary_Contact__c);
                obj.eSecondary_Contact_Email__c = c.Email;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I took the liberty of doing some code formatting and casing to adjust to best practices and normal conventions.

PPS: As David Reed mentioned on his comment, this could very well be better made as a formula field. I am correcting your trigger for education purposes, but you should probably prefer a formula here, or even a Process Builder, instead of a trigger.

Comment: Thanks that works like a charm